# PHP Undefined variable: errorString

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I can't seem to figure out what the errors are. Please help.

> Notice: Undefined variable: errorString in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/finalproject/donate/thankyou.php
>   on line 95
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: messageString in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/finalproject/donate/thankyou.php
>   on line 99

```
<?php

require "config.php";
require "connect.php";

if(isset($_POST['submitform']) && isset($_POST['txn_id']))
{
    $_POST['nameField'] = esc($_POST['nameField']);
    $_POST['websiteField'] =  esc($_POST['websiteField']);
    $_POST['messageField'] = esc($_POST['messageField']);

    $error = array();

    if(mb_strlen($_POST['nameField'],"utf-8")<2)
    {
        $error[] = 'Please fill in a valid name.';
    }

    if(mb_strlen($_POST['messageField'],"utf-8")<2)
    {
        $error[] = 'Please fill in a longer message.';
    }

    if(!validateURL($_POST['websiteField']))
    {
        $error[] = 'The URL you entered is invalid.';
    }

    $errorString = '';
    if(count($error))
    {
        $errorString = join('<br />',$error);
    }
    else
    {
        mysql_query("   INSERT INTO dc_comments (transaction_id, name, url, message)
                        VALUES (
                            '".esc($_POST['txn_id'])."',
                            '".$_POST['nameField']."',
                            '".$_POST['websiteField']."',
                            '".$_POST['messageField']."'
                        )");

        if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1)
        {
            $messageString = '<a href="donate.php">You were added to our donor list! &raquo;</a>';
        }
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Thank you!</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

</head>

<body class="thankyouPage">

<div id="main">
    <h1>Thank you!</h1>
    <h2>Add Yourself to our Donor Section</h2>

    <div class="lightSection">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="nameField">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="nameField" name="nameField" />
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label for="websiteField">Web Site</label>
                <input type="text" id="websiteField" name="websiteField" />
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label for="messageField">Message</label>
                <textarea name="messageField" id="messageField"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="button">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                <input type="hidden" name="submitform" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="txn_id" value="<?php echo $_POST['txn_id']?>" />
            </div>
        </form>

        <?php
        if($errorString)
        {
            echo '<p class="error">'.$errorString.'</p>';
        }
        else if($messageString)
        {
            echo '<p class="success">'.$messageString.'</p>';
        }
        ?>

    </div>


</body>
</html>


<?php

function esc($str)
{
    global $link;

    if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
            $str = stripslashes($str);

    return mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($str)),$link);
}

function validateURL($str)
{
    return preg_match('/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;\/~\+#])?/i',$str);
}
?>
```

Comment: Try replacing `if($errorString)` with `if(isset($errorString))`

Comment: You only set `$errorString` and `$messageString` if you've entered your first `if` statement. Therefore, if this statement is not entered, these variables are never created.

Comment: `i cant seem to figure out what are the errors, please help` Is not a question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: We can't see which lines are 95 and 99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using errorString outside the main if statement, initialize it before.

Move `$errorString = '';`

before

`if(isset($_POST['submitform']) && isset($_POST['txn_id']))`

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `$errorString` within your first if statement, which means it will not be defined if `$_POST['submitform']` and `$_POST['txn_id']` are not set.

You are then using `$errorsString` after this if statement. You should make sure that `$errorString` is defined in the correct scope:

```
$errorString = '';
if(isset($_POST['submitform']) && isset($_POST['txn_id']))
{
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if($errorString) {
    echo '<p class="error">'.$errorString.'</p>';
}
else if($messageString)
{
    echo '<p class="success">'.$messageString.'</p>';
}
```

for

```
if(isset($errorString)) {
    echo '<p class="error">'.$errorString.'</p>';
} elseif (isset($messageString)) {
    echo '<p class="success">'.$messageString.'</p>';
}
```